# Embed flex in asp .net...not working :(

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex

I know the things im missing here are tiny but yet im missing them...heres what im doing 
I just copied Flex builder's generated html from the  tags, and pasted in an ASP .NET page, the page shows up no errors , I can see a grey rectable the size of my flex file but there's nothing in it its blank .... and I am stumped why ???? Why when it's showing up perfectly fine via the HTML file that flex generates. I need help someone please enlighten me :(

My Code:

```
----------
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
            id="SlidemFX" width="796px" height="900px"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
            <param name="movie" value="SlidemFX.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#869ca7" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <embed src="SlidemFX.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7"
                width="796px" height="900px" name="SlidemFX"   align="middle"
                play="true"
                loop="false"
                quality="high"
                allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
                type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
            </embed>
    </object>
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied `SlidemFX.swf` and any other SWF's or assets being loaded by that swf into the asp pages location?

Comment: Yes I did copy everything from the flex folder into the asp .net project folder.

Comment: P.S , I haven't called any external resources from the flex app. its simply calling a webservice and display the response.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put the Flex application itself in the right location relative to your ASP page.

Comment: You mean, the flex project folder ?

Comment: I just copied the entire flex project folder into the asp .net project folder, but its still only showing me the grey box without the actual swf. Is there something that needs to be configured in the IIS or the Visual studio 2008 development server for swf(s) ?